# Displaying large amount of data

Tags: flutter, charts, bluetooth, time-series, display

I am working on a mobile application using Bluetooth sensor. My goal is to visualize Bluetooth data on graph. I have 3 different pages on my mobile application:

- First page having 3 channels (you can imagine it as as 1 graph and 3 signals, thus 3 curves)
- Second page having 8 channels
- Third page having 3 channels

The moment I have many channels (like at the second page, 8 channels) the display is slowing down. It is so slow that I cannot even switch between pages. Like if I am clicking but nothing is happening, totally freezed.

I am guessing it is because of the display library that I am using. For those who already have experienced the same issue, any suggestions about real-time charts in Flutter? I have already tested Syncfusion and it is indeed freezing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because having discovered many libraries, I kind of found the answer: I have tested [Flutter Charts](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) library. It works perfectly fine and looks good. Even though I am displaying +3 channel per page, it is not lagging and I can easily switch between pages.

Answer (score 2):

We tried to replicate the reported scenario by creating the chart based on the shared information i.e., in first page and third page, we have a chart with 3 series, in the second page we have a chart with 8 series. And updated the charts for every 300ms, and we ran the application more than an hour, unfortunately the app didn’t get freeze. We have tried by adding the data to the chart and not removed any data in the above case.

For better performance we suggest using the fast line series and for updating the data source use the updateDataSource and not use set state. The set state will render the re-render the chart, the updateDataSource method will skip old data points processing, unnecessary bounds calculation, etc. For more information on these, find the user guide below.

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types/fast-line-chart https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/methods#updatedatasource

We have also attached the sample below which we have used for testing,

Sample link https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/stackoverflow1887344518.zip

Also, if you are using large data set, we suggest using the on-demand loading feature. For more information this, find the user guide and sample below. If this suits to your requirement, you can make use of this.

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/on-demand-loading
Demo: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/infinite-scrolling